# jquery slider with checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, slider, radio-button

`http://jsfiddle.net/RwH5A/42/` 
here is my jsfiddle code, what i want to accomplish is get the checkbox act like a radio button
this is my code for the uncheck

```
$('#check1').click(function()
{
    $('#check2').prop('checked', false); 
    $('#check3').prop('checked', false); 
}); 
$('#check2').click(function()
{  
    $('#check1').prop('checked', false); 
    $('#check3').prop('checked', false); 
});
 $('#check3').click(function()
{  
    $('#check1').prop('checked', false); 
    $('#check2').prop('checked', false); 
});
```

---

Here try this http://jsfiddle.net/RwH5A/40/ the only problem here is it adds every time i check a checkbox

Comment: So why not use a `radio`?

Comment: im trying to create a form the same like this www.myclean.com

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$Check.click(function() {
    $Check.not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f2mh6/)

Comment: thanks!, the radio button effect is there, but the price is not updating as i check the checkbox and also the value of each checkbox are 15 why is that?

Comment: thanks again!, but still the price is not automatically updated when checkbox is check, and you made it only 1 can be chose :), can you please make it just like a radio button but don't disable the other two

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.removeAttr('checked');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/f2mh6/2/

Comment: you all have the same effect and the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question. I must say your question could have been more explicit too :)

You have to get the value of both the slider and the checkbox, which I call option. However if no checkbox is checked, the option value must be set to 0. Besides your code must be refactored out in both places. That was the trick.

The following statement:

```
var option = $('input:checkbox:checked').val() || 0;
```

means that the checkbox's associated value must be grab if selected or set to 0 if nothing is selected. The rest of the code is easily understandable I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2mh6/7/

Hope this helps,

R.

Comment: still the same roland :(

Comment: try this please the only problem here is it always add every check http://jsfiddle.net/RwH5A/40/

Comment: See my answer, which has been completed :)

Answer (score 0):

My own personal approach would be:

```
$Check.change(function(){
    var self = this,
        v = parseInt(self.value, 10);
    $Check.prop('checked', function(){
        return this == self && self.checked;
    });
    CurrPrice += (self.checked ? Math.abs(v) : -Math.abs(v));
    setprice(CurrPrice);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RwH5A/44/).

References:

- [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I changed it to radio button, please look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080905/radio-button-act-like-checkbox

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2zaz/9/

$("input:checkbox").click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings(':checked').prop('checked', false);
   
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        options = Number(this.value);
        calculatePrice();
    } else {
        options = 0;
        calculatePrice();
    }
});

it's fix :) thanks!