# Radio-button act like checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":radio").behaveLikeCheckbox();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Zq/172/).

I got the code from [here](http://www.digitss.com/jquery/radio-with-checkbox-behavior.html). My problem is that I can't make it work.

Can someone help?

Comment: Where is behaveLikeCheckbox() function? Your fiddle and probably code is missed to include js file with this function...

Comment: Why can't you use checkboxes, rather than radio buttons that act like them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery and the behaveLikeCheckbox plugin to make this work.  Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mq8Zq/174/

So in your HTML document:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="relative/path/to/plugin/or/cdn"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(":radio").behaveLikeCheckbox();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2zaz/9/

$("input:checkbox").click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings(':checked').prop('checked', false);
   
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        options = Number(this.value);
        calculatePrice();
    } else {
        options = 0;
        calculatePrice();
    }
});

it's fix :) thanks!

Comment: So you wanted check boxes to behave like radios?

Comment: yes it's done :) this is my next prob after finishing the first step
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083242/create-a-form-similar-to-a-website

Answer (score 0):

sadly, that example page doesn't explain anything...

looking at the source code of the page, it seems that you have to include jquery and the extension for the behavior

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.radio.checkbox.behavior.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include some JS files : JQuery, and the plugin for the checkbox.
Like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.digitss.com/jquery/jquery.radio.checkbox.behavior.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(":radio").behaveLikeCheckbox();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is put a different "name" to your Radios. When you put the same name to them, only one gets "selected".

Answer (score -1):

Make type="checkbox" and name Same