# create a form similar to a website

Tags: php, forms, web

Help please create a form similar to a website.
How can i achieve a form like in this website www.myclean.com, i already got the first step in the form which is the slider and checkbox.
Now I need to know how to process that information and put it in the another page please try the form in this site www.myclean.com.
I can only think of php to do this get or post, do you have other ideas?

Thanks! :)

here is what I did in my slider and checkbox.

`jsfiddle.net/z2zaz/9/`

Comment: Dude, do not expect anyone here to do something for you without even trying. Whatever, good luck.

Comment: Dude i didn't stop trying, i just want to know if others have other or better ideas to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can process the form in nearly any language you'd like, or you can [email the results to yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail), but I'd recommend against that due to all the spam bots.

The language doesn't really matter. PHP is a fine solution, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: OK thank you! :), then i'll use php how do you think about the calendar in the second page after submitting the form?..how can i do that? it's jqeury but is that a specific calendar plugin?

Comment: It's part of jQuery/jQuery UI. There's also HTML input type `date`, but it's not 100% supported, so check out Modernizr (http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/)